# Apple Watch HealthKitManager not working after update to watchOS 4.2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit

I've been reading the heart rate from the Apple Watch (Series 2) but, after updating to OS4.2.2 yesterday (and updating the iPhone 7 to the latest OS, iOS 11.2.5), calling createHeartRateStreamingQuery() from the HealthKitManager stopped working on my device.

The code wasn't changed and things still work on the simulator.  For reference, here's the code (the invocation that is working in the simulator but seems to not work on the device after the update is in the if-let statement within the .running case):

```
func workoutSession(_ workoutSession : HKWorkoutSession, didChangeTo toState: HKWorkoutSessionState, from fromState: HKWorkoutSessionState, date: Date) {
    switch toState {
    case .running:
        guard let workoutStartDate = workoutStartDate else {
            print(workoutStartDate)
            return
        }
        if let query = healthKitManager.createHeartRateStreamingQuery(workoutStartDate) {
            self.heartRateQuery = query
            self.healthKitManager.heartRateDelegate = self
            healthKitManager.healthStore.execute(query)
        }
    case .ended:
        print("Workout ended")
        if let query = self.heartRateQuery {
            healthKitManager.healthStore.stop(query)
        }
    default:
        print("Other workout state")
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?  Or, has anyone else had a problem with the Apple Watch/Healthkit since the update?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Things are working now and I'm guessing it has to do with when I set the workout date.  I had set the workout date before I created the workout session.  Now I'm doing it just after the workout session is created.  That's the only substantial change I made fumbling around for possible solutions.